# How can I close another application from my application in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, exit

I need it so that my program cannot be opened twice. Is there a way that I can close another application from my application?

Comment: If this is a winforms application, you can just change the config and it will handle it for you.

Comment: Since it’s your own program, you can probably go into your project settings and check the single-instance application box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a screenshot showing the option mentioned by @minitech.

Project --> Properties --> Application Tab --> "Make single instance application":

[image: Make Single Instance Application]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can run a second copy by using the run dialog and entering: YOURPROGRAM /secondary

Comment: Never heard of such a thing @chipperyman573...can you provide a link to any documentation on this feature?